# discord rewrite I need to do a task when Bot gets kicked or leaves a server

Tags: discord.py

discord rewrite I need to do a task when Bot gets kicked or leaves a server!
I need it to delete its data from sqlite database!
I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on_guild_remove` event.

From [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove):

> `discord.on_guild_remove(guild)`
>
> Called when a Guild is removed from the Client.
>
> This happens through, but not limited to, these circumstances:
>
> - The client got banned.
> - The client got kicked.
> - The client left the guild.
> - The client or the guild owner deleted the guild.
>
> In order for this event to be invoked then the Client must have been part of the guild to begin with. (i.e. it is part of `Client.guilds`)
>
> *Parameters*
>
> guild (Guild) – The guild that got removed.

Comment: Thanks but there's one problem when bot is offline then it doesn't get removed and my bot NEEDS right data

Comment: @MrStretch Check the `.guilds` property on startup? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.guilds